# How to change pd.read_excel() engine based on input file extension?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I was using the below code to read the data in sheets into dataframes:

```
binary_file = requests.get(url_to_excel_file).content
workbook = pd.ExcelFile(binary_file)
# then get the dataframes from the multiple sheets i need
df1 = pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet_name = sheet_name_A, index_col=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet_name = sheet_name_B, index_col=None)
```

However, in the newest xlrd library, support for XLSX was removed for some reason.

**Question:**
Given that I might receive xls or xlsx in the url, how would I get df1 and df2?

Comment: xlrd will only do xls files.  Support for xlsx has been withdrawn.  You could read xlsx files using pandas by dropping back a version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Answer**

Depending on the file type, set the engine in the ExcelFile constructor.

```
if extension == "xls":
    pd.ExcelFile(binary_file, engine = "xlrd")
elif extension == "xlsx":
    pd.ExcelFile(binary_file, engine = "openpyxl")
```